How to perform nested one-to-many join in LINQ
I apologize if this is stupid, but how to return an IEnumerable<Receipt> that contains Product in this case:
// Each Receipt can have many ReceiptDetals
public class Receipt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReceiptDetail> ReceiptDetails { get; set; }  = new List<ReceiptDetail>();
}


// Each ReceiptDetail is related to one Product
public class ReceiptDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    // Other properties ....
    public int ProductId { get; set; }   
    public Product Product { get; set; } = new Product();
}

// A Product can be present in none or many ReceiptDetails !!!
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set;}  
    // Other properties ...
    public virtual ICollection<ReceiptDetail> ReceiptDetails { get; set; } = new List<ReceiptDetail>();
}

context.Receipt.Include(m => m.ReceiptDetail) returns a list of Receipt, with included ReceiptDetails, but Product within ReceiptDetails is NULL !
Also, context.Receipt.Include(m => m.ReceiptDetal).Include(x => x.Product) does not work, and neither does context.Receipt.Include(m => m.ReceiptDetal.Product) ...
What am I missing ?
Any suggestions or help is appreciated !

Do you mean ReceiptDetails where you have ReceiptDetail or ReceiptDetal? Also, what version of .Net and EF?

I think you missed ThenInclude, but we don't know the EF version.

Yes, ThenInclude did it ! Thank you !!

Below code may work for you.
context.Product.Include(p => p.Receipt).ThenInclude(r => r.ReceiptDetail)

